# Simulation in a web browser

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation, webgl

I am simulating a tshirt on a person in blender. Everything is working fine but I am looking for a way how to put it on my internet site so it will be animated together. I have found three.js which is really helpful but I am looking for a way of putting animation which is interacting with other object and has been previously calculated in blender. When I do export an glb/gltf file and import it again in blender I see that cloth property on a tshirt and collision property on my person are gone and animation of both things together does not work. I tried also fbx with same results. Any idea how this could be achieved?

Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 1):

The modifier for cloth physics exists only in Blender — there is no way to export it to any format I'm aware of. You can either set up a new physics simulation in a physics engine compatible three.js (which may give different results!) or bake your animation.

For workflows to "bake" the animation, see [Cloth Bake: Save frames in timeline as shape key?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51230/cloth-bake-save-frames-in-timeline-as-shape-key) and https://blenderartists.org/t/export-bezier-curve-animation-as-gltf-and-or-fbx/1151423/4.