Export cloth simulation to USDc file at specific frame

I´m not a Blender expert but I finished a simple project, that I now try to get into DaVinci Fusion.
I decided to export it as an USDc File., which works fine except one thing.
The Blender project is a cloth simulation. And and the end of the simulation it looks great, but when I export the USDC File it always gives me the first frame. I tried  baking, or reducing the timeline to the wanted frame. But Whatever I do the export will still give the first not the last frame.

First : This looks more suitable for the davinci forum. Second : when you said that you get the first frame and you want the last, are talking about a still or you mean you want the whole animation but you don't get the animation in resolve?. Third : have you tried any other format or do you specifically need Usd?

Thank you very much.
The idea is just to get the finished 3d model as it is shown after the simulation to include it into the movie as a character.
I tried FBX but it did not include the right material.
So the best way would be to have the model like it is shown after the simulation as an model without the animation of the falling cloth.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43154/how-to-export-a-scene-with-shape-keys-animation https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51230/cloth-bake-save-frames-in-timeline-as-shape-key

You could try this : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244004/how-can-i-do-a-cartoon-like-cannon-firing-animation-thats-compatible-with-unity/244018#244018

Thank you very much. I will try it

Hi,
so yeah it worked so far. Thanks a lot. That was a real help. Now I will try to add a small walking cycle and then try it again. We will see.
